# echo table from database on site stays blank

Tags: php, mysql, session

thank you for reading my message. I am working on a website, but whenever I want to display a number from a database field on the website, no errors, but nothing is shown.

(sorry for bad english)

auth

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}
```

login

```
  require('db.php');
session_start();
// When form submitted, check and create user session.
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);    // removes backslashes
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
    $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);
    // Check user is exist in the database
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username'
                 AND password='" . md5($password) . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysql_error());
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($rows == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['coins'] = $coins;
        // Redirect to user dashboard page
        header("Location: dashboard-2.php");
    } else {
        echo "<div class='form'>
              <h3>Je wachtwoord of gebruikersnaam is onjuist.</h3><br/>
              <p class='link'>Klik hier om <a href='login.php'>terug</a> te gaan.</p>
              </div>";
    }
} else {
```

*coins need to be shown on the dashboard.*

Comment: `mysql_error()` < that won't work with mysqli_. So, if you have mysql errors, it won't catch them. Plus, is error reporting enabled?

Comment: Why are you using MD5 as opposed to `password_hash()`? You should also be using prepared statements instead.

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Something is not shown up? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: @funkfortyniner i haven't code this btw.

Comment: @davidev i want to echo field coins in the database.

Comment: Okay, it there a coins field in users table? You are using $coins? Where is it declared / initalized?

Comment: Add this to the top of your php files `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and use `mysqli_error($con)`. If any errors, let us know what they were.

Comment: @davidev yes i made a field coins in the users table. i dont have declared or initalized it. don't know how. ;)

Comment: Given the answers now; this appears to just be a typographical error.

Comment: `if ($rows == 1)` < what do you think will happen if there are more than one row?

Comment: @funkfortyniner undefined index: coins

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong here:

1. `mysql_error()` cannot be used with "mysqlixxx": they're two completely different libraries.
   Use [mysqli::error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) instead.
2. You should NEVER, EVER, *NEVER EVER* use raw user input in a SQL statement.
   Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.
3. Finally, the reason you're not seeing "coins" ... is because you never read anything from the result set.

   SUGGESTION: `$coins = $rows[0]['coins'];`

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $_SESSION['coins'] to an undefined variable ($coins). You have to fetch a row from the result set, e.g. [mysqli_fetch_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Try this:

```
    if ($rows == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['coins'] = $row->coins; //Your column for coins in your table.
        // Redirect to user dashboard page
        header("Location: dashboard-2.php");
    } else {
        echo "<div class='form'>
              <h3>Je wachtwoord of gebruikersnaam is onjuist.</h3><br/>
              <p class='link'>Klik hier om <a href='login.php'>terug</a> te gaan.</p>
              </div>";
    }
```